# About less loop, throw error

Tags: loops, less

```
.loop (@start, @end, @step, @className,@propertyName) when (@start < @end) {
  .@{className}-@{start} {
    @{propertyName}: @start * 1px;
  }
  .loop (@start + @step, @end, @step, @className, @propertyName);
}


.loop(12,48,2,fs,font-size);
```

I want loop css common class,but throw Error,I don't where the error is on.
for example:

```
.fs-12{
font-size:12px;
}

.fs-13{
font-size:13px;
}

.mt-13{
margin-top:13px;
}
```

Comment: This code compiles fine with the reference Less compiler (with `--strict-math=off` option).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.loop (@start, @end, @step, @className,@propertyName) when (@start < @end) {
  .@{className}-@{start} {
    @{propertyName}: (@start * 1px);
  }
  .loop ((@start + @step), @end, @step, @className, @propertyName);
}



 .loop(12,48,2, fs, font-size);
```

Comment: That basically means you have your [`--strict-math=on`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math). If your answer yourself please put more details in the answer.

Comment: @seven-phases-max, I just rebuild twitter boostrap, my careless to do so, I find the config on the Gruntfile.js, thanks.